# Is it possible to order records in a report using a field that isn't shown on it?

Tags: reporting, custom-field, order

Title is self explanatory, but here's an example:

I have an object that has a certain numeric field that is unique, and want to make a report using the said field to sort the lines. Is it possible not to show the field column in the report?

For example, I have 4 records like:

Field - Name

- 2 - Catarina
- 3 - George
- 1 - John
- 4 - Cindy

But in the report I want it shown as:

- John
- Catarina
- George
- Cindy

Without showing the control field.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with AppExchange product Conga Composer which takes either SFDC Report(s) or SFDC SOQL query(s) and merges them into an Excel template (1 or more worksheets). You can choose which of the report/query fields end up in your template that is rendered to the end user.

Conga is a paid app (I don't work for them but have used it for years). They have terrific customer support.